# Update table after ngResource (mongolabResource) save

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

New to `JS framework` but have Java, JQuery etc background. (Not that seems to help with Angular.)

I am using PKozlowski's excellent [adapter](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab) for Angular and don't know how to update the UI (plain vanilla table) when I save a row.

Conceptually, the table lists disabled students and after saving the new name and email, it should update the already displayed table.

This is in app.js:

```
app.controller('StudentCtrl', function($scope, Student){

      $scope.students = Student.query();

      $scope.addStudent = function() {
            var name = $scope.newName;
            var email = $scope.newEmail;

            var newStudent = Student.save({name: name, email: email});
            $scope.newName = '';
            $scope.email = '';
      }
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="mainContainer" ng-controller="StudentCtrl">
    <input type="search" id="studentSearchbox" ng-model="studentSearch"></input>
    <div id="studentsList">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Student Email</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="student in students | filter:studentSearch" ng-class-even="'even'" >
                        <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{student._id.$oid}}
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <div id="addStudentDiv">
            <h2>Add Student</h2>
            <label ng-model="newStudent">{{newStudent.name}}</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname-Lastname" ng-model="newName">Student Name</input>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="newEmail"></input>
            <button type="button" ng-click="addStudent()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML also?

Comment: Posted the HTML. Think I might have an answer.

In the JS code, I put this line below var newStudent =
    $scope.students.push(newStudent);

Is there anything I can study to learn Javascript better to properly understand angular? I thought I knew JS but it seems only for JQuery and simple functions, pretty lost when I read some of the Angular docs.

Comment: I think the solution might be:
$scope.students.push(newStudent);
after the Student.save but don't know if that's the correct way.

Comment: Yes that looks right upon seeing your HTML. As for recommended reading, I would [start with MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "angular" way but my solution was to put this

```
$scope.students.push(newStudent);
```

after

```
var newStudent = Student.save({name: name, email: email});
```